# How should we tag questions about live/online play?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

There's currently a tag [brick-and-mortar](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brick-and-mortar) as well as [live](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live).  Similarly there are tags [online-poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-poker) and [online](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online).  There are other possible variations that haven't happened to come up yet ("live-poker" for instance).

So I think it's pretty clear that there are two major categories here and that we need synonyms ([brick-and-mortar](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brick-and-mortar) / [live](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live) should be synonyms and [online-poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-poker) / [online](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) should be synonyms).  However, which names should be the main names?  Are there other synonyms we need to worry about?

I think a large portion of questions will be tagged with one of these two, so it's important to do this right.  I also think questions that relate equally to both can be left without one of these tags, but if you disagree you can include why in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

"Poker" in a tag is redundant and should be discouraged.

I like "live" and "online" for their simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Rely on the auto-completion of this system. If a user has a question about live play, they are going to type in L-I-V… to which will pop up [live-play](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-play). <-- That would be my choice. Anything else would be ambiguous.

For online play, the uses types in O-N-L-I… to which he will see [online-play](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-play). <-- Again, completely unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

"live" feels ambiguous to me, but I am probably an outlier.

My vote goes to [bricks-and-mortar] and [online-poker] being the primaries. No ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "live" and "online" play, as these are most common with online poker media, tournament coverage and content.